# How to intermediary transfer files from other servers using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php script that connects to a certain server and downloads the file from that server. Now I'm trying my best to hide this download location so that the user cannot find out where the hidden folder is (on the remote server).

So what I did was try the readfile(url) method, this worked like a charm except it was extremely slow. I'm guessing that Readfile first downloads the file in some form into my server from the remote server and to the client, thats why its slower?

I was hoping there might be another solution out there that can just act as an intermediary without disturbing the download speed.

@EDIT------- Tried cURL but speed still suffers------

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 $filename='newfile.rar';
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Cache-Control: private",false);
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\";");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Content-Length: '.'20000000');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// allow redirects
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_callback');
 curl_exec($ch);

 function write_callback($ch, $data) {
 echo $data;
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
 return strlen($data);
```

Comment: readfile shouldn't buffer the file...so you don't stand to gain any speed via curl or other methods.

Comment: @chris, Good to know!  Learn something new every day.  In that case, Zakukashi, the speed issue isn't going away.  After all, it is only going to be as fast as your server can download the file from the remote server.  Since you aren't getting any faster with cURL, then that seems to confirm what Chris is saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple proxy with cURL by using its various callbacks.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Basically, you'll want to specify the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` option value to be a function that echos that data to the client.  Don't forget to flush buffers when doing this.

That way, while your server downloads the file, it will be simultaneously sending it to the client.

More info here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

---

**Edit:** I guess an example is in order.  Note, I haven't tested this code, but this should get you started...

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.whatever.com/something");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_callback');

function write_callback($ch, $data) {
    echo $data;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    return strlen($data);
}
```

Comment: I haven't done much work with cURL, could you show me an example of what you mean? All of the examples I find is to download with cURL into your server which I dont need because I dont want to save the file in the server.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to loop this or monitor the amount bytes that were downloaded by the client.

Comment: No, there is no looping.  That write callback function gets called multiple times.  The length of `$data` is the size of the current buffered chunk.  You'll see this all when you call `curl_exec()`.

Comment: I see how it works now, but I'm experiencing an odd problem. The page displays nothing when I put in the URL of the hidden file. No errors are displayed either. But when I put in a link of an image from another server for example(http://www.ifc.com/news/assets_c/pans-labyrinth-04052011.jpg) it works. I know my url works because testing it with readfile always works and redirecting works too it seems only the cURL doesn't?

Comment: Nevermind, I got to fix this issue by putting in the option curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

Comment: I finally got it working how you mentioned but the speed still suffers tremendously. See my last Edit on the intial post.

Comment: @Zakukashi, You say the speed suffers.... is there a long pause before content is sent at all?  Or is it just slow?  You can't fix it if it is just slow, as your server is likely on a crap connection.  You can determine this by using Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to do this. Here is a basic example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.domain.com/file.php");
curl_exec($ch);
```

This will call the url, and load it into the current browser. If you just want to store this data in a variable you can do the following:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.domain.com/file.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How can I make it so it starts downloading for the user?